# In CNN model How can we find the initialized values of the filters that we have used

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have the cnn model code.

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, input_shape = 
(256,256,3),activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
```

So now i need to find what values the 32 filters were initialized with ? Any code that helps in printing the values of the filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the corresponding layer from the model

```
layer = classifier.layers[0]  # 0th layer is the convolution in your architecture
```

There will be two variables for each convolution layer (Filter kernels and Bias). Get the corresponding one

```
filters = layer.weights[0]  # kernel is the 0th index
```

Now filters contain the values you are looking for and it is a tensor. To get the values of the tensor, use get_value() function of Keras backend

```
import keras.backend as K
print(K.get_value(wt))
```

This will print an array of shape (3, 3, 3, 32) which translates to 32 filters of kernel size 3x3 for 3 channels.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sir, by any chance can i get the output of "classifier = Sequential()" layer ?

Comment: That's not a layer. Only model initialization. The actual layers starts once you call classifier.add() function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the default keras Conv2d initialization : `kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'` (or `init='glorot_uniform'` for older version of keras).

You can look at what this initializer does here : [Keras initializers](https://keras.io/initializers/)

Finally, here is one way to access the weights of your first layer :

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, input_shape = 
(256,256,3),activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

first_layer = classifier.layers[0]
print(first_layer.get_weights()) # You may need to process this output tensor to get a readable output and not just a raw tensor
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sir, by any chance can i get the output of "classifier = Sequential()" layer ?